# Ajax tabContainer properties setting

Tags: c#, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm creating Admin Panel using Ajax tab container which has 5 tapPanels and in that each tapPanel, I have one Panel from standard tool. And in that each Panel, I have GridView to show added data. And finally, I have one Add button outside of the Ajax tabContainer. The problem is, I only can ADD the 1st tap which is SPLASH, if I add 2nd tap MAIN_CATEGORY, either the program adds the data into SPLASH or shows me an error msg "FK constrain" but my DB design is fine. I've found out the reason. It actually depends on which TAP was clicked on when I run. For example, in the bottom right pix, MAIN_CATEGORY is clicked, if I view in browser now, I can add it without any problem but it'll show the problem if I move to other tap and add. So I assume it might be the setting. Please refer to the pix.

[image: My current setting VS 2012]

My current Source Code

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
                <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabConAddInfo" ActiveTabIndex="2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnClientActiveTabChanged="tabChanged" OnActiveTabChanged="btnAddCat_Click" >
                    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tapSplash" HeaderText="Splash" ActiveTabIndex="0" runat="server"><HeaderTemplate>Splash</HeaderTemplate>

                        <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >
                             <%-- My textboxes and labels --%>

                            <div style= "Overflow:scroll ;max-height: 200px; width: auto" >

                                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewAddSplash" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VersionNumber" HeaderText="Version #" >
                                        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LoginID" HeaderText="Admin ID" >                                       
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tapMainCat" runat="server" HeaderText="Main Category" ActiveTabIndex="1" ><HeaderTemplate>Main Category</HeaderTemplate>

                    <ContentTemplate>                           
                            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" >                              
                                <%-- My textboxes and labels --%>
```

My current C# code

```
protected void btnAddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = (AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer)TabConAddInfo;
            int index = container.ActiveTabIndex;

            if (index == 0)
            {
                addSplash();
            }
            else if (index == 1)
            {
                addMainCat();
            }

  protected void TabConAddInfo_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //I have this but don't know how it works and I prefer ADD to action not the TAB  
        }
```

// I have tried

```
protected void btnAddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    int CurrentTab = TabConAddInfo.ActiveTabIndex;
                switch (CurrentTab)
                {
                    case 0:
                        addSplash();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        addMainCat();
                        break;
    }
```

//Also tried

```
protected void btnAddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = (AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer)TabConAddInfo;
            AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tcTabPanel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();


            if (tcTabPanel.HeaderText == "SPLASH")
            {
                addSplash();
            }
            else if (tcTabPanel.HeaderText == "MAIN_CATEGORY")
            {
                addMainCat();
            }
```

I'm very new to programming and I have no idea how to use Javascript Functions. Is Javascrip function thing is must to know to get this work??? If so, can it be written on source code or C# code page without creating JS files??

I hope I explained clear Thanks!

Added One more pic
[image: TabIndex value still "0"]

Comment: Firstly, is my tabContainer setting right? Thanks~

Comment: Just added a new photo in the bottom after Hiral's suggestion. Thanks~

Comment: Activetabindex Add in Only Tabcontainer Not in TabPanel And in TabPanel add Only TabIndex then on button click event you used Tabcontainer ID.ActiveTab.TabIndex as per Condition

Comment: Thanks Hiral. Yes, I've removed ActiveTabIndex from TabPanel after I saw the warnings from VS but still doesn't work...... :( and is it normal behavior that all 5 Tab's TabIndex is still showing "0" even if I've changed in source code? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

1) ajaxtoolkit:tabcontainer =  add property  AS activetabindex="0"

2) ajaxToolkit:TabPanel tapSplash = add property  AS TabIndex="0"

3)  ajaxToolkit:TabPanel tapMainCat= add property  AS TabIndex="1"

Then

try this

```
protected void btnAddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TabConAddInfo.ActiveTab.TabIndex == 0)
    {
        addSplash();
    }
    else if (TabConAddInfo.ActiveTab.TabIndex == 1)
    {
        addMainCat();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hiral~ Thanks for trying helping me again~

Comment: I've added TabIndex="0" then "2" etc in the source code but they have not changed in the Properties window. They all saying TabIndex "0".  And the same problem is still there....... Like I said " It depends on which TAP was clicked on the time I run in VS design page. For example, in the bottom right pix, MAIN_CATEGORY is clicked, if I run to view in browser now, I can add MAIN_CATEGORY without any problem but it'll show the problem if I move to other tap and add." So I assume it might be the setting. Is my setting right? Thanks~

Comment: Problem solved! It was just the properties setting as I assumed! You can also see it in my first pic with a comment in red. I've deleted OnClientActiveTabChanged and it works! :) I actually don't know what it does but anyway. All of the coding I've tried works fine including Hiral's one. Thanks~